# Customizing search layout

Tags: page-layout, search-layout

After a recent migration, our client reported that the search layouts on almost all objects don't match with each other. Reporting, that the pagers styles are not in sync. (see images) 
After searching I couldn't come up with anything to customize the pagers (footer) of search layout. Why are they different anyways. 
Source org: Enterprise edition.  API version: 31 
Target org: Enterprise edition. API version: 31

**Source Org**
[image: Source Org]

**Target Org**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you show, a likely explanation is that the number of records is not known to the list view in your "Target Org" and so the number of pages can't be shown. In the bottom left the number of records is shown as 2000+ not a specific number. In the "Source Org" where the number of records is small, they can be counted and so the number of pages is shown.

You can check this theory by looking at the list views of other objects that have more than or less than 2000 records.

Presumably this is a platform performance optimization to avoid counting all the rows where there are a large number of rows.